# How to convert Hexadecimal to Double in Dart?

Tags: android, dart, floating-point, hex, double

By receiving coordinates encoded as hex, how could I convert them into a double value so that I get a true value of those coordinates? I already tried converting from hex to int and then to double, but I couldn't get the correct value. Is there a Dart package that could this?

I tried the `double.parse()` return Invalid Double Exception

For reference I have the following hex as a String:

> 4044B84189374BC1

That should return something like this:

> 41.43949999999996

I tested with those online converters but I couldn't find a way to do this in Dart language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit wonky but the following seems to do the trick:

```dart
import 'dart:typed_data';

void main() {
  print(convert('4044B84189374BC1')); // 41.43949999999996
}

double convert(String hexString) =>
    (ByteData(8)..setUint64(0, int.parse(hexString, radix: 16))).getFloat64(0);
```

The idea is that I assume the hex string are an normal integer. I then take the 64-bit bits from this int and puts into a bytebuffer and then read this buffer as if it contains a double.

### Improved solution based on feedback from lrn

The previous suggested solution have the flaw to not work when compiled to JavaScript (since integers in JavaScript does not have 64-bit precision). The following fixes this by handling the parsing in 32-bit parts:

```dart
import 'dart:typed_data';

void main() {
  print(convert('4044B84189374BC1')); // 41.43949999999996
}

double convert(String hexString) {
  String hexStringPadded = hexString.padLeft(16, '0');

  return (ByteData(8)
        ..setInt32(0, int.parse(hexStringPadded.substring(0, 8), radix: 16))
        ..setInt32(4, int.parse(hexStringPadded.substring(8, 16), radix: 16)))
      .getFloat64(0);
}
```

The "wonkyness" are still strong since both solutions are still very much dependent on how `int` and `double` are stored in the memory, which can change depending on the CPU architecture. The answer here is very much designed specifically for the provided example in the question.

Comment: This only works on the native VM. When compiled to JavaScript, integers do not have 64 bits of precision. You can instead parse the hex into two 32-bit integers, store them adjacently in a buffer, and read back the double. (Also be aware that not all CPUs store doubles and integers in the same ways, or with the same endianness).

Comment: @lrn Added the suggested solution (hope it is correct :) ). But I agree the solution are still wonky because of potential problems with other CPU architectures.